# Drag and drop target separate from Sortable container

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-draggable, knockout-sortable

I'm trying to set up drag and drop cloning with Knockout and jQuery,  but I can't figure this bit out.
I have [the knockout-sortable binding that Niemeyer wrote](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable),  but I can't find a way to hook it up how I'd like.

I was hoping the `connectClass` would be able to "catch" drops and pass them into the child element Sortable, but apparently not.  Here's a fiddle I forked from Niemeyer that shows pretty simply what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kal_Torak/g74xN/3/

My Sortable bound elements aren't always going to have items in them, so the list itself won't be visible, so I need to be able to drop anywhere on the parent container and have them added as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a little `droppable` binding that plays nice with the `sortable` and `draggable` bindings.  There are a few ways that you could do it, but here is one way where you pass a handler to droppable and it calls the handler passing the new item as the first argument.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.droppable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var dropHandler = valueAccessor() || {};

        $(element).droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
               var item = ko.utils.domData.get(ui.draggable[0], "ko_dragItem");

                if (item) {
                    item = item.clone ? item.clone() : item;
                    dropHandler.call(this, item, event, ui);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Then, you would bind it like:

```
<div id="main" data-bind="droppable: addTask">
```

With `addTask` pushing to your observbaleArray.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3JBnh/