# knockout sortable table - drop to empty tbody

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I am trying to emulate part of Drupal Admin where you can drag items around in a table to re-order them. You can also drag items to a 'hidden' section of the table.

- ==VISIBLE==
- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3
- ==HIDDEN==
- Element 4

When there are no hidden items the table shows a row that says 'no hidden items':

- ==VISIBLE==
- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3
- Element 4
- ==HIDDEN==
- No hidden items

I have tried to do this with a table that has **two tbody tags**, one with visible items and one with hidden items.

Problem: you can't drag and drop elements to an **empty tbody** - there are no pixels to drop onto.
Problem 2: Showing the 'No hidden items' message.

**EDIT**

[drupal style re-order items, with bugs](http://jsfiddle.net/monk_e_boy/pL0t7o1q/6/)

```
// too much code to paste here
```

This example sort of works in Chrome as you can drop to an empty list, but not in Firefox. See 'problem 2' above, the message should act as a big drop target.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far :-)

Comment: OK, let me set up a fiddle

Comment: Thanks, looking into it

Comment: would this [separate sortable container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803408/drag-and-drop-target-separate-from-sortable-container?rq=1) be of use? Have a hidden tbody with a row in it that is only visible when the $root.hidden().length is zero? I am trying to get it to work, but failing :(

Comment: Well, that's the exact thing I am doing. I will update you on it.

Comment: please mark as an answer if you found it useful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve it..

Apply a CSS which will increase the padding of placeholder when hidden array is empty.

```
<tbody data-bind="css: hidden().length === 0 ? 'empty-placeholder' : '', sortable: { data: hidden, options: { handle: '.sortableHandle', cursor: 'move' } }">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data" class="sortableHandle"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Add this CSS in stylesheet. Customize as per your choice but keep the padding or space so that drop event will be able to pickup the target.

```
.empty-placeholder{
    display:block;
    padding:10px 0;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
}
```

JSFIddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/pL0t7o1q/9/

Comment: Wow, a million thanks! That is a really elegant solution :) ... I made a tiny modification to make your solution similar to the Drupal Admin interface [example](http://jsfiddle.net/monk_e_boy/pL0t7o1q/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way to fix this issue. Add an observer to both arrays, **visible** and **hidden**.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.visible = ko.observableArray(data.visible);
    self.hidden = ko.observableArray(data.hidden);

    // add an empty array placeholder to give the tbody 
    // a tr to show - else it is empty and zero pixels high
    // and impossible to drop anything onto
    self.hidden.subscribe(function(newVal){

        if (self.hidden().length>1) {
            // remove the [no element placeholder]
            self.hidden.remove(function(item) { return item.label == '##empty##' });
        }

        if (self.hidden().length==0) {
            // push something into the table so the tbody is non-zero height
            self.hidden.push({label: '##empty##'});
        }
    });

}
```

Then in the HTML I used an < !-- ko if: label == '##empty##' --> No hidden items < !-- /ko --> to display a message when the list was empty.

Note: if you do use this method, each item in the list (or in my case, each row in the table) needs the jQuery UI 'sortable handle class'. Putting in a table row without that class will break it.